# Destination Mac-Address Visibility in Forward Chain (forward hook) of nftables!

Tags: nftables

I am trying to write some rules like below:

```
chain forward { # handle 3 
      type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;    
         ether daddr 3c:22:fb:73:0b:7d jump forward-daddr-3c-22-fb-73-0b-7d # handle 31            
         ether saddr 5c:87:9c:d8:fa:9a jump forward-saddr-5c-87-9c-d8-fa-9a # handle 32
         ether daddr 5c:87:9c:d8:fa:9a counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump forward-daddr-5c-87-9c-d8-fa-9a # handle 33                                          
         ether saddr 64:80:99:c6:64:ed jump forward-saddr-64-80-99-c6-64-ed # handle 34
         ether daddr 64:80:99:c6:64:ed jump forward-daddr-64-80-99-c6-64-ed # handle 35
         ether saddr a8:bd:27:cc:a5:b8 jump forward-saddr-a8-bd-27-cc-a5-b8 # handle 36
         ether daddr a8:bd:27:cc:a5:b8 jump forward-daddr-a8-bd-27-cc-a5-b8 # handle 37
         ether saddr f4:be:ec:c0:ab:a7 jump forward-saddr-f4-be-ec-c0-ab-a7 # handle 38
         ether daddr f4:be:ec:c0:ab:a7 jump forward-daddr-f4-be-ec-c0-ab-a7 # handle 39
         ip daddr 172.16.30.101 counter packets 26 bytes 1664 jump forward-daddr-5c-87-9c-d8-fa-9a # handle 56    }
```

But, I don't see any match happening based on destination MAC addresses even though they are valid. Does the forward chain get to see the destination MAC address or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
I want to add forwarding rule purely based on mac-addresses. Let's say I have a device A (mac-address mA) accessing a device B (mac-address mB) on tcp port 80. Both these devices are connected to my routing device and they cannot talk to each other directly.

I want to add a rule that device-A should talk to only device-B on Port-80 and rest of the traffic should be dropped.
Similarly device-B should be able to receive packets from device-A and rest of the traffic should be dropped. device-B may additionally have a rule to receive packets from device-C (for which an additional rule can be configured).

Comment: The destination MAC address of a packet when traversing the ip forward path is the MAC address of the interface it arrived on. It's not the future MAC address of the future system it will be routed to or through which is yet unknown. So can you clarify your goal ([XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Y: "use ether daddr", X ?), give the complete ruleset (including the table) and to ponder options, your kernel version?

Comment: @A.B Thanks for your response. I have updated more details in my query.

Comment: kernel version? It might matter for feature availability. Anyway if it's just preventing the wrong device to receive traffic that's one thing, if it's really routing by MAC, that's something else much more difficult. Bridging (and filtering on the bridge) would be easier.